# error : Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: javascript

in my react error Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

```
const handleIndexScore = () => { 
    setScore (score >= 80) ? "A" : (score >= 70) ? "B" : (score >= 60) ? "C" : (score >= 50) ? "D" : "E"
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPwxT.png)

Comment: `setScore (score >= 80)` <--- you are calling set score. You are not using the A, B, C in setScore.... `setScore((score >= 80)......."E")`

Comment: I've tried it but it still has an error, in my vscode there is no error, there is no warning, but on the browser display there is an error

Comment: `setScore((score >= 80) ? "A" : (score >= 70) ? "B" : (score >= 60) ? "C" : (score >= 50) ? "D" : "E")` should not be throwing the no unused expressions error.

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to do:

```
setScore (score >= 80 ? "A" : (score >= 70) ? "B" : (score >= 60) ? "C" : (score >= 50) ? "D" : "E")
```

What you basically do now is:

```
let x = setScore (score >= 80)
x ? "A" : (score >= 70) ? "B" : (score >= 60) ? "C" : (score >= 50) ? "D" : "E"
```